# Listen to an Animation/Transition between Activities

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I have two activities in my app. The second activity should be launched with an animation from the bottom of the screen. I want to make it look like as if only the content of the page changes and the action bar remains on top of the screen. To achieve this I need to listen to the animation so I can make the action bar of the second activity visible as soon as the animation is finished.

I start the second activity like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.SOME_ID, id);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = 
        ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation
        (this, R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_down);
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

My question is: How can I listen to the animation and if that is not possible, what is the best way to listen to an animation between activities?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Shared Element Transitions** which are by default supporting by android.

**1. Enable Window Content Transitions**

Enable Window Content Transitions in your styles.xml file:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**2. Assign a Common Transition Name**

Assign a common transition name to the shared elements in both layouts. Use the android:transitionName attribute.

For e.g. in MainActivity.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  ...>
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
          android:transitionName="profile"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="160dp" />
      ...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In DetailActivity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  ...>
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
          android:transitionName="profile"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="380dp" />
      ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that it doesn't matter if the android:id is different or where in the layout hierarchy the source and target views exist.

**3. Start Activity**

Start the target activity by specifying a bundle of those shared elements and views from the source.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
// Pass data object in the bundle and populate details activity.
intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT, contact);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View)ivProfile, "profile");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Thats it! Specifying the source view along with the transition name ensures that even if you have multiple views with the same transition name in the source hierarchy, it will essentially be able to pick the right view to start the animation from.

To reverse the scene transition animation when you finish the second activity, call the `Activity.supportFinishAfterTransition()` method instead of `Activity.finish()`. Also, you will need to override the behavior of the home button in the ToolBar/ ActionBar for such cases:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            supportFinishAfterTransition();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**4. Multiple Shared Elements**

Sometimes, you might want to animate multiple elements from the source view hierarchy. This can be achieved by using distinct transition names in the source and target layout xml files.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT, contact);
Pair<View, String> p1 = Pair.create((View)ivProfile, "profile");
Pair<View, String> p2 = Pair.create(vPalette, "palette");
Pair<View, String> p3 = Pair.create((View)tvName, "text");
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, p1, p2, p3);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Note: By default android.util.Pair will be imported but we want to select the android.support.v4.util.Pair class instead.

Be careful to not overdo transitions between shared elements. While it can make sense to have one cohesive unit animate from one screen to another (which may or may not contain multiple shared elements), having too many shared elements will result in a distracting animation which makes the experience more jarring.

**5. Customizing Shared Elements Transition**

In Android L, shared elements transition defaults to a combination of ChangeBounds, ChangeTransform, ChangeImageTransform, and ChangeClipBounds. This works well for most typical cases. However, you may customize this behavior or even define your own custom transition.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- enable window content transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

    <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
    <!-- options are: explode, slide, fade -->
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/change_image_transform</item>

    <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
      @transition/change_image_transform</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
      @transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

The change_image_transform transition in this example is defined as follows:

```
<!-- res/transition/change_image_transform.xml -->
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <changeImageTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

To enable window content transitions at runtime instead, call the `Window.requestFeature()` method:

```
// inside your activity (if you did not enable transitions in your theme)
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
// set an enter transition
getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
// set an exit transition
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```